# Strange parameters on Wordpress pages which weren't created by me

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that has been indexed. I have set "No Index" to Archive, Category, Tag and Author pages.

I am seeing pages which I didn't create being indexed like:

```
domain.com/page/2/?p=xyzabc
domain.com/page/3/?p=xyzabc   
domain.com/page/4/?p=xyzabc
```

Each of these pages would display 10 of my posts, so it looks somewhat like a post archive.

Question:

1. Where do I delete these pages?
2. How do I prevent these pages with strange parameters being created in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you caught a WP virus. You can find plugins that provide "anti-virus" - install and run them.

Also, it's likely your server files were corrupted. I suggest downloading the WordPress source files and comparing it to your server so you can safely delete files that don't belong.

If that's the case.

Comment: I am using Hostgator shared hosting. There's a new site I want to set up. Should I avoid this current hosting account and set up a new Hostgator shared hosting account for my new website? If I stick to the current hosting account does that mean the new website will face the same issue?

Comment: Honestly, it's not the web host. It's WordPress. And really, it's not even WordPress' fault either. It's the widespread popularity. WP isn't really any less secure than any other CMS, but the problem is that it being so well known makes it a target. I make the same point to gungho Mac users who claim Windows is a virus-infested trap.

Download a anti-virus plugin, set it up to scan on a schedule. Delete malicious files, after that, you should be fine.